# changing the img src with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, src, prop

The html structure I have is something like:

```
<ul id="something">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://domain.com/directory/file1-128x79.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://domain.com/directory/file2-128x79.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://domain.com/directory/file3-128x79.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to change the filename from **file#-128x79.jpg** to **file#-896x277.jpg**.

I don't know how to take the dynamically generated filename and search and replace for the src changes.

I found my way to replacing the whole src with 'none' to make sure I got it right so far, but I don't know how to do the rest.

```
$('#something').removeAttr('id').prop('class', 'some-class').find('img').prop('src', 'none');
```

Comment: replace none with the filename

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can replace the `src` for each `img` by first selecting all the images with a selector and then using the `attr` callback to `replace` the contents:

```
$('#something img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return e.replace("-128x79.jpg","-896x277.jpg");
})
```

Comment: thanks.. i took the .attr() and replaced the second .prop() and it worked perfectly..

Comment: Your statement that prop() is only used to assign boolean properties is incorrect.  It's used to assign any DOM properties.  src is an HTML attribute (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr, T.J Crowder's explanation).  jQuery changed again in 1.6.1 (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/).  Setting an img src using either prop() or attr() seems to work for me.  Tested with  jquery 1.6.1 and 1.7.1 on Chrome 17, IE 8/9 and Firefox 10.

Comment: @mhenry1384 Just like how you can get boolean properties with `attr`, you can get non-boolean properties with `prop`. If you'd read the link you referred to (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/), the **preferred usage** is defined as 'The .prop() method should be used for boolean attributes/properties and for properties which do not exist in html (such as window.location). All other attributes (ones you can see in the html) can and should continue to be manipulated with the .attr() method.'

Comment: +1 for the distinction and reference to 1.6.1 docs with preferred usage. In your answer, the note that prop is used to assign boolean properties is clarified with your comment "... and for properties which do not exist...". Perhaps edit the answer to include that condition.

Comment: Regarding "_Note that prop is used to assign boolean properties_" Not sure if it was ever true but not anymore.

Comment: @coviex I've removed the comment

Answer (score 6):

you can assign an id to your image tag like

```
<img id ="pic" src="http://domain.com/directory/file3-128x79.jpg">
```

then in jquery use

```
$('#pic').attr('src', 'file#-896x277.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F6Gds/14/)

```
$('img').hover(function(){ // or any other method
    this.src = this.src.replace("128x79", "200x60");         
});
```

Comment: But when you move mouse away the source stays reaplaced, what should i do to swap back the source to starting position?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `.children()` before `.find('img')`:

```
$('#something').removeAttr('id').attr('class', 'some-class').children().find('img').attr('src', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Note : try the following here mouse over is just for the demo purpose only

```
$(function() {
    $("something li a img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = "over.gif";
            $(this).attr("src", src); // change the image source
        })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
this.removeAttr('id').prop('class', 'featured-images').find('img').attr({‘src’:'file#-896x277.jpg’});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#something img').attr('src',$('#something img').attr('src').replace(x,y))
```