# Changing default img style in Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, content-management-system

I am trying to override the default img tag style when a category is set to a blog.

I have changed the html editor and tried numerous things inside the CMS but nothing lets me remove or change the added style attribute. This is how it comes out:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" alt="alt text" width="100" height="123" style=" float:left; margin: 3px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"/>
```

I need to hack out the style part, just remove it all so I can use the style sheet to style it.

I have found this jquery method: [changing the img src with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568424/changing-the-img-src-with-jquery)

```
    <script>
    $('.items-leading img').attr('style',function(i,e){
 return e.replace("float:left; margin: 3px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;","");
});

  </script>
```

And added it to the top of the  tag. But it doesn't work ;(

Please help !

Comment: can't understand well, be more specific plz, And also tell the joomla version if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want remove style of img tags, simply use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $('.items-leading img').css({});
    });
</script>
```