# Changing pictures with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing the img src with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568424/changing-the-img-src-with-jquery)

The title may make this sound easy, and it probably is. but i, with my incredibly small knowledge of js, am finding it incredibly nerve wracking... basically i have pictures set in a form (lets say img1 img2 and img3) and i want the user to be able to click on an image and it will change to a different one, for instance you click on img1 and it becomes img1a. and etc, heres the code:

```
<form>
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center">
<label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="/images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest3" id="label-interest3"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

there are currently checkboxes, however those will be hidden, so i need the images to change on click to show the user that it is in fact selected, any ideas guys?

Comment: `$("label img").click(function(){$(this).attr("src", "myNewImage.png");})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image tag add an onclick event and add the javascript there to change the image source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
    var img1= document.getElementById("img1");

    if(img1.name == "on")
    {
        img1.src = "/images/" + "img1a.jpg";
        img1.name = "off";
    }
    else
    {
        img1.src = "/images/" + "img1.jpg";
        img1.name = "on";
    }
}
</script>

<img src="/images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" id="img1" name="on" />
```

Comment: Well, its a shove in the right direction i suppose however it still doesnt explain how to do it

Comment: well, it did work swtiching once, but as i need the user to be able to deselect it, how would i go about having it switch back? would i just have to write it again backwards :X sorry still learning here

Comment: Its not the most beautiful solution but it will get the job done, there is a nice jquery function that alternates beetween two images i cant remember it now but will update my answer when i find it.

Comment: hate to be the bearer of bad news, especially with how much your helping, but on this one on click nothing changes. any ideas why?

Comment: probobly becasuse i used == insteed of === to compare the strings

Comment: nope still nothing :/ is it working on your end

Comment: now it should work as you wanted it to :)

Comment: people like you make the internet a better place, it worked perfect :) sorry im pretty good at everything from bare bones html do scripting for db's except when it comes to js, if you know a good book i can sit bown and get started with i would love to hear it :)

Comment: Thanks :)  Im no expert at javascript either but check out Crockfords videos at this site the are a good start http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use another image, you can differentiate the existing image.

Use a css class:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .selected {
            outline: solid 2px blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="selected" src="http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/extensions/BMO/web/images/mozchomp.gif" />
</body>
```

using javascript, change the className to "selected" to get a highlighting effect or to "" (nothing, empty) for unselecting.

(Or use inline css style attribute `style="outline: solid 2px blue"`)